# mapbox map cuts off sometimes

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have implemented US map in my angular application using ngx-mapbox-gl

The problem I am facing is that the map sometimes(randomly) cuts off in the middle and does not fill the enclosing div

The component template is as below:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 map-height-sm">
   <mgl-map #map1 
        [style]="'mapbox://styles/xxx'" 
        [zoom]="[4]"
        [maxZoom]="maxZoom"
        [center]="[-95.7129, 37.0902]"
        [fitBounds]="bounds"
        [fitBoundsOptions]="boundsOptions">
        <mgl-control mglNavigation [showCompass]="false"></mgl-control>
        <ngContainer *ngFor="let d of Deals">
               <mgl-marker #myMarker [lngLat]="lngLat[d.deal_id]">
                   <div class="marker"></div>
                   <span><b>{{ d.deal_name }}</b></span>
               </mgl-marker>
               <mgl-popup [marker]="myMarker" class="" [closeButton]="true" [closeOnClick]="false"
               [anchor]="'top'">
                   <div class="marker-popup-details">
                   Dummy popup
                   </div>
               </mgl-popup>
        </ngContainer>
    </mgl-map>
</div>
```

Kindly advise

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack but it is what solved a similar issue for me. Mapboxgl-map class was overriding my position:absolute to position:relative and it was causing all kinds of problems. By moving the css into a  tag on the html page for the map id and the body, it was heavy enough weight to stop mapboxgl-map from doing this. I also had it where the map wouldn't show up or it would be halfway open but my planes i was rendering where off the map on white background.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<title>MyApp</title>
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```